# Best place(s) to share my scripts with others?

Tags: .net, powershell, vbscript, sharing

Would anyone recommend a site (or sites) where one could share scripts they have written that they think may be helpful to others? There are so many, and so many that appear defunct, I am hesitant to arbitrarily pick one. My scripts are mostly PowerShell with the occasional VBS or .NET mixed in for good measure.

Having finally achieved the level of Advanced Scripting Padewan, I think I'm ready to share some of my work with the community at large. :)

Comment: For Microsoft scripts you can post in Microsoft Script Center: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub gist is a nice place to share code snippets. If your scripts are small, you can pick one. Or just create an open repository on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I set up a Github repository and am trying that out now!